# Declare and initialize in a method that has the same name as the class and data type

Tags: java, class, variables, netbeans

I am new to object oriented programming and I am trying to declare and initialize left, but I don't know how to do it. I tried

```
left = new Counter(4, left.mod);
```

But it Netbeans is saying that

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Number

This is not the real program.

```
public class Number{

    private int mod;
    public Number(int modulus, Number left) {
        mod = modulus;
        //how to declare left?
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to implement some sort of linked list etc. Obviously you want left to be remembered, so declare it just like any other normal property of the class.

```
public class Number{
    private Number left;
    private int mod;
    public Number(int modulus, Number left) {
        mod = modulus;
        this.left = left;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this.left? I always see this.something. I would like to know what is this....?

Comment: Since there are two left here, one is the parameter got passed in, and one is the property, we need a way to differentiate them. this means this instance/myself - so this.left is the property left of this instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to interact with two classes that have the same name in a class, you'll have to use the fully-qualified name to refer to one or the other. So, if for instance you want to refer to a `java.lang.Number` inside your own `Number` class, you'd do

```
public class Number{
    private java.lang.Number left;
    private int mod;

    public Number(int modulus, java.lang.Number left) {
        mod = modulus;
        this.left = left;
    }
}
```

(note that my emphasis on *really* is indicating that, as you can probably already guess, it's generally more trouble than it's worth to give a class the same name as a commonly-used library type).